# Got an error while connecting to database

Tags: python, linux, psycopg2

I am unable to connected to database in linux using psycopg2. I have postgresql installed in linux and my code is:

```
import psycopg2

def testEgg():

    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = myDatabase user = postgres port = 5432")

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE egg ( num integer, data varchar);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO egg values ( 1, 'A');")
    conn.commit()

    cur.execute("SELECT num from egg;")
    row = cur.fetchone()

    print row

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

testEgg()
```

And the I got the error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

This code runs well in `windows7` but got above mentioned error in `linux`. 
Is there anything I need to do more in linux?  Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem due to your code, but due to the permission of the postgres user.

You should create a new user to access to your database and replace this :

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = myDatabase user = postgres port = 5432")
```

by (replace `<your_user>` by your real user name ...)

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = myDatabase user = <your_user> port = 5432")
```

To create a new user on postgres, you can use the 'createuser' binary. The documentation is available [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but when i did that, that is, when i tried to create user , still I get  "Ident authentication failed" error , the code is:  # createuser -S -D -R -E  testUser 
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "root"

Comment: When you are connect with the root user, just tape : "su - postgres". Then, you can run createuser easily...